# Pandas - concatenating two multi-index dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataframe as follows:

```
df.head()
                Student Name            Q1  Q2  Q3
Month   Roll No             
2016-08-01  0   Save Mithil Vinay       0.0 0.0 0.0
            1   Abraham Ancy Chandy     6.0 5.0 5.0
            2   Barabde Pranjal Sanjiv  7.0 5.0 5.0
            3   Bari Siddhesh Kishor    8.0 5.0 3.0
            4   Barretto Cleon Domnic   1.0 5.0 4.0
```

Now I wanted to make a hierarchical column index, so I did it the following way:

```
big_df = pd.concat([df['Student Name'], df[['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3']]], axis=1, keys=['Name', 'IS'])
```

and was able to get the following:

```
>>> big_df
                Name                    IS
                Student Name            Q1  Q2  Q3
Month   Roll No             
2016-08-01  0   Save Mithil Vinay       0.0 0.0 0.0
            1   Abraham Ancy Chandy     6.0 5.0 5.0
            2   Barabde Pranjal Sanjiv  7.0 5.0 5.0
            3   Bari Siddhesh Kishor    8.0 5.0 3.0
            4   Barretto Cleon Domnic   1.0 5.0 4.0
```

Now for the second iteration, I want to concatenate only the `Q1, Q2, Q3` values  from the new dataframe to the `big_df` dataframe (the previously concatenated dataframe). Now the dataframe for the second iteration is as follows:

```
                Student Name            Q1  Q2  Q3
Month   Roll No             
2016-08-01  0   Save Mithil Vinay       0.0 0.0 0.0
            1   Abraham Ancy Chandy     8.0 5.0 5.0
            2   Barabde Pranjal Sanjiv  7.0 5.0 4.0
            3   Bari Siddhesh Kishor    8.0 4.0 3.0
            4   Barretto Cleon Domnic   2.0 3.0 4.0
```

I wanted the `big_df` like the following:

```
                Name                    IS          CC
                Student Name            Q1  Q2  Q3  Q1  Q2  Q3
Month   Roll No                             
2016-08-01  0   Save Mithil Vinay       0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
            1   Abraham Ancy Chandy     6.0 5.0 5.0 8.0 5.0 5.0
            2   Barabde Pranjal Sanjiv  7.0 5.0 5.0 7.0 5.0 4.0
            3   Bari Siddhesh Kishor    8.0 5.0 3.0 8.0 4.0 3.0
            4   Barretto Cleon Domnic   1.0 5.0 4.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
```

I tried the following codes, but all are giving error:

```
big_df.concat([df[['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3']]], axis=1, keys=['CC'])

pd.concat([big_df, df[['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3']]], axis=1, keys=['Name', 'CC'])
```

Where am I doing the error? Kindly help. I am new to Pandas

Comment: It would be awesome if when you post questions you format your question with something where one can simply copy and use pd.read_clipboard() to get the initial data. You should test that it works, and that will also highlight which arguments are needed in read_clipboard() or a couple of post-processing lines to get exactly your dataframes. That will make it much easier for anyone to help.

Comment: @JulienMarrec Sorry about that... Will improve it next time. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're way better off setting your index to be `['Month', 'Roll no.', 'Student Name']`. That will simplify your concat syntaxes a lot and ensure you match on the name of the students too.

```
df.set_index('Student Name', append=True, inplace=True)
```

Second, I suggest you do it differently and store your `df` dataframes (with the Q1/Q2/Q3 values) during your iteration with a reference to the name for the highest column level (e.g.: 'IS', 'CC'). A dict would be perfect for this, and pandas does accept a dict as an argument to `pd.concat`

```
# Creating a dictionnary with the first df from your question
df_dict = {'IS': df}

# Iterate....
   # Append the new df to the df_dict
   df_dict['CC'] = df
```

Now, after looping through, here's your dict:

```
df_dict

In [10]: df_dict

Out[10]:
{'CC':                                             Q1   Q2   Q3
 Month      Roll No Student Name                         
 2016-08-01 0       Save Mithil Vinay       0.0  0.0  0.0
            1       Abraham Ancy Chandy     6.0  5.0  5.0
            2       Barabde Pranjal Sanjiv  7.0  5.0  5.0
            3       Bari Siddhesh Kisho     8.0  5.0  3.0
            4       Barretto Cleon Domnic   1.0  5.0  4.0,
 'IS':                                             Q1   Q2   Q3
 Month      Roll No Student Name                         
 2016-08-01 0       Save Mithil Vinay       0.0  0.0  0.0
            1       Abraham Ancy Chandy     8.0  5.0  5.0
            2       Barabde Pranjal Sanjiv  7.0  5.0  4.0
            3       Bari Siddhesh Kisho     8.0  4.0  3.0
            4       Barretto Cleon Domnic   2.0  3.0  4.0}
```

So now if you concat, pandas does it nicely, and automatically for you:

```
In [11]: big_df = pd.concat(df_dict, axis=1)
         big_df

Out[11]:
```

[image]

---

If you really wanted to do it iteratively, you should prepend your new multilevel ('CC') before concat with big_df

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('IS', x) for x in df.columns])

# Then you can concat, give the same result as the picture above.
pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the `Student Name` is getting concatenated. [Image1](https://i.imgsafe.org/08d67d6aff.png) and [Image2](https://i.imgsafe.org/08d93130b9.png). How to remove `Student Name`?

Comment: I think you missed the part where I said you should set your index as ['Month', 'Roll No', 'Student Name']. 

For you:, you need to do `df.set_index('Student Name', append=True, inplace=True)` before

Comment: Worked perfectly.. Thanks a lot... And sorry for not posting the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the topmost level of `big_df`:

```
big_df.columns = big_df.columns.droplevel(level=0)
```

Concatenate them providing three different frames as input matching the number of keys to be used:

```
Q_cols = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3']
key_names = ['Name', 'IS', 'CC']
pd.concat([big_df[['Student Name']], big_df[Q_cols], df[Q_cols]], axis=1, keys=key_names)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I needed to drop `level 0`. That was creating the problem.