# change the level of a column, when concat two data frames with the same column

Tags: python, pandas

referral url : [Pandas - concatenating two multi-index dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464706/pandas-concatenating-two-multi-index-dataframes)

result what I want

```
                Name                    Q1     Q2    Q3 
                Student Name            IS CC  IS CC IS CC
Month   Roll No                             
2016-08-01  0   Save Mithil Vinay       ...
            1   Abraham Ancy Chandy     
            2   Barabde Pranjal Sanjiv  
            3   Bari Siddhesh Kishor    
            4   Barretto Cleon Domnic
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.columns=df.columns.droplevel(level=0)`

Comment: Thanks how to set level of columns? I only found multi index. It is maybe level of index(row)